# Material ui auto width Grid container

Tags: material-ui

How can I have a Grid container with auto width? I want to my grid fit it's content
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-78uld

I want to keep red box as minimum as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao, you could set `width: "fit-content"` in `container` class in this way:

```
container: {
   backgroundColor: "red",
   width: "fit-content"
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ieot8?file=/demo.js) your codesandbox modified.